# Convert blank values to zero when using the Query function

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

Is there a way to convert data going into a `query()` function so that blank/null values are converted to zero?

I have a dataset with three columns:

```
Group    AC       Plan
Comms    350      [blank]
IT       50,000   85,000
Rent     15,000   15,000
Training [blank]  8,500
```

I want to query the set to find the difference between AC and Plan, 
e.g.
`=query('data', "select A, B-C",1)`. However, since the query omits blank cells when calculating `B-C`, the result is like this:

```
Group    Diff
Comms    [blank]
IT       -35,000
Rent     0
Training [blank]
```

When I wanted this:

```
Group    Diff
Comms    350
IT       -35,000
Rent     0
Training -8,500
```

Before you go wild: I am **not** able to change the source data (the incoming data is actually another `query()` using the `pivot` functionality). And the reason I need this to work is I use a `limit` clause to confine the results to only the top 25 and bottom 25 differences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(QUERY(T3:V7)="", 0, QUERY(T3:V7)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks, while this works, it is an expensive workaround given the processing that's needed for arrayformula(). Here I was hoping for an undocumented feature in the language but I guess we're not there yet. My sheet is fairly large and slow already and has a few of those queries.

Comment: They definitely need the ability to coerce values. Adding the ability via the "options" clause seems the easiest for the users. Maybe adding a new clause like "coerce" could work, too??

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski there isnt such parameter in google sheets like "coerce" - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Comment: Yeah, the current version is 0.7 ... Nothing says a newer version can't add functionality like that

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid ARRAYFORMULA by using MAP + LAMBDA functions. Looks shorter and faster with my large dataset in Sheets.

```
=MAP(your_query, LAMBDA(X, IF(X="", 0, X)))
```

Think of X as a math variable here.
It represents any output from the first argument.